# Undefined class 'DragSelectionUpdateCallback' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

From flutter version 3.10.0 'DragSelectionUpdateCallback' has been removed from text_selection.dart
What is the alternative to this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of DragSelectionUpdateCallback, you can use the new TextSelectionGestureDetector class to handle text selection gestures.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTextSelectionGestureDetector extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final Function(TextSelection) onSelectionChanged;

  MyTextSelectionGestureDetector({required this.controller, required this.onSelectionChanged});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextSelectionGestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onTapDown: (_) => controller.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: controller.text.length),
      onSelectionChanged: onSelectionChanged,
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```